# At what point are exceptions raised when using Django's ORM

Tags: django, django-orm

Simple enough example - I have a bit of Django code that starts with a queryset...

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
```

Later on it performs various filtering, depending on some configurable options...

```
if something:
    queryset = self.queryset.filter(foo=some_foo)

if another_thing:
    queryset = self.queryset.filter(bar=some_bar)
```

And finally it performs the lookup...

```
try:
    obj = queryset.get()
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    raise ValidationError('Does not exist')
```

Now, because of the flexible way that the filtering needs to occur, it's possible that the `some_foo` or `some_bar` variables might not be of the correct type (eg. we could end up with an empty string attempting to filter against an integer field.) so it's possible for this code to end up raising a `TypeError` or a `ValueError`.

That's fine, and I can handle the case appropriately, but what's not clear to me from the ORM contract, is *at what point* should I expect those exceptions to be raised.

- Will it occur on the `.filter()` statement?...
- ...or on the `.get()` statement?...
- ...or is in underspecified, and I handle it as able to occur on either?  (Eg perhaps depending on the implementation of the database backend?)

Comment: maybe i'm missing something but i need to ask: why are you calling get on the queryset? filter() and get() have different purposes and they both perform a query. and filter() is the first one querying --> the Type/Value error will be raised during the filtering. you won't reach the get()

Comment: Note: Okay, I can see in this particular case it appears to be raised by the `.get()` statement (which is what I expected) but it's not clear if I can safely rely on this behavior to be consistent.

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo The filter statements may be chained.  The final `.get()` is the bit that performs the lookup of a single object, given the query.

Comment: yes, i know how they work :) i was just wondering why you mix them (i never do that, actually; and i'm not sure it's a good practice, since they have REALLY different meaning). if you perform an "empty" get() on a batch of objects (like you're doing) you'll be suffering of a MultipleObjectsReturned error (See the docs). that's why i'm asking :) they do the same thing in the same way but expect different results. you should use get with parameters if you want to filter your results and receive just one obj.

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo <shrug>  It's a sensible enough thing to be doing in my particular context, and the lookup is guaranteed to return either 0 or 1 results, as either or both of the chained filters will be unique.

Comment: @TomChristie If both chanined filters are unique and you are sure that it will return either 0 or 1 record then why you just don't use a `.get`? Another thing if you try to filter an integer field with empty string or even None value there will be no `ValueError` or `TypeError` exceptions are going to raised. It will simply try to filter them using the values you gave it.

Comment: Haven't seen ValueError in such case, do you have an example? AttributeError is raised immediately on the .filter() statement when lookup is resolved and invalid keyword argument is found, as it stands in Django Documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the original question, a `FieldError` and `ValueError` are raised on the call to filter, when a new queryset is built:

```
>>> a = Account.objects.all()
>>> a = a.filter(id=3)
>>> a = a.filter(no_exist=3)
<snip>
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'no_exist' into field. Choices are: active, created_on, group, id, ...

>>> a = Account.objects.all()
>>> a = a.filter(id='abc')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'abc'
```

I'll also add that this pattern seems misleading to me, in that `filter` is normally used to return a list/iterable of models, rather than *one* as with `get`.  For clarity and easier handling of the exceptions, I'd suggest this pattern:

```python
kwargs = {}
if something:
    kwargs['foo'] = some_foo
if another_thing:
    kwargs['bar'] = some_bar

# handle if kwargs is empty
try:
    obj = MyModel.objects.get(**kwargs)
except (FieldError, ValueError, ObjectDoesNotExist):
    raise ValidationError('Does not exist')
```

The other added benefit is that, IIRC, the work of cloning querysets is relatively expensive, so you ignore that overhead, while at the same time making the code cleaner.  Going back to your question, with this pattern there's no question where the exception will be raised.

Comment: The `kwargs` pattern probably is nicer.  The `FieldError` exception (incorrect field name) is a slightly different case to the `TypeError` (incorrect type supplied to the filter).  The former appears to occur immediately, but the later appears to happen when the lookup is actually made.  Still, I'll accept the answer as I think the kwarg pattern is the right way to deal with the ambiguity.